# Exception starting Worklight server on Tomcat

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I move the application from dev to producation,change the application-description.xml and worklight.properties files and generate a .war file,and then i add it to the tomcat,but when I start tomcat,it occur the follow error:

```
   java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Class org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver not found in Worklight platform or project
```

but even I add the hsql.jar to my application,it still the error,any help?
    my worklight version is 5.0.5 and  apache-tomcat-7.0.37 and mysql is 5.1.57

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HSQL is the default database used when running the Worklight project in Eclipse.
When you move to Tomcat, you also need to edit in worklight.properties the database-related properties.

Since you mentioned MySQL, you need to uncomment the MySQL section in worklight.properties and edit it according to your setup.

Of course, also undeploy and re-deploy the updated .war file.

**Additions:**
HSQL is a filesystem-driven database, and is provided by Worklight to work out-of-the-box, when running in Eclipse.

When moving to Tomcat and installing Worklight in it, you must edit worklight.properties and set it up so that it will know how to talk with the datbase.

In your case, when using MySQL you must also include in Tomcat's \lib folder the MySQL connector/J file. You can get it from here: http://www.mysql.com/downloads/mirror.php?id=412178 (click on "No thanks, just start my download" at the bottom).

Note that in order to run Worklight on an Application Server (such as Tomcat, WebSphere or Liberty), **you must use either the Consumer or Enterprise Edition of Worklight**. This is required as otherwise you will not have the Worklight JEE .jar file as well as the SQL scripts to create the database tables. All of this is done via the IBM Installation Manager.

You cannot use Worklight on an Application Server using the Developer Edition.